# ERROR: Cached plan must not change result type for multi-tenant DB

Tags: postgresql, schema, psql, multi-tenant, search-path

We've been getting `ERROR: Cached plan must not change result type.` on our application intermittently. Upon checking our Postgres logs, seems like it happens when `SET SESSION search_path to 'sample';` is called.

I have attached also the logs of our DB for clarity, but I can't still figure out what's happening.

Appreciate any help!

[Postgres DB logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLImO.jpg)

Comment: Check if you have objects with the same name (like tables) between `sample` schema and whatever else you have and most likely where prepared statement was created. If you do, check if column types match.

Comment: Hi Lukasz! Thanks for your answer.

We don't have any objects in `sample` schema that has the same name, though we have other schemas that has the same tables as what's in `sample` but I'm pretty sure they have the same table definition.

Comment: I meant objects that are different, but share the same name and are on different schemas. Second explanation is that definition of object changed after prepared statement was created and then it was executed.

Comment: Apologies. We actually do have objects with the same name on different schemas but they all have the same column types as I have mentioned. We're thinking maybe the error happens when a change schema is happening but another prepared statement is still executing or about to be executed for another schema.

Comment: Those schema changes are only for session that executes them, so they will have no effect on others. Can't really say much more about cause for this unless you can show how to reproduce it. I managed to get the same effect when I had 2 tables with different types. If you can make sure that prepared statement is created after changing schema and `DEALLOCATE` it if you plan on changing schema within session then error will likely go away.